# How do I get Intellij IDEA 12.0 to work with Play Framework 2.1.0 app and Scala 2.10.0?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, playframework-2.1, sbt-idea

So I've been trying to get IDEA 12.0 to work with Play 2.1.0 and Scala 2.10.0. I've just about given up because it's not working for me the way I want it to. Here is a copy of my `build.properties`, `Build.scala`, and `plugins.sbt`. I followed the approach on the playframework site to execute `idea with-sources=yes` in the play console. I've also tried adding `sbt-idea` plugin version 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT as seen in plugins.sbt, but nothing seems to work if I want to reference a new view template I just created or a new route. The only way I can work in IDEA is if I have a console open and run `sbt compile`, go back to IDEA, and it will refresh itself and recognize the new view templates or routes.

`plugins.sbt`

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

scalaVersion := "2.10.0"

// The Typesafe repository 
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"
// Sonatype snapshots to get sbt-idea 1.3.0-SNAPSHOT
//resolvers += "Sonatype snapshots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.0")
//addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.3.0-SNAPSHOT")
```

`build.properties`

```
sbt.version=0.12.2
```

`Build.scala`

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import play.Project._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "admin-application"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    jdbc,
    anorm
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here      
  )
}
```

Comment: That's how I work. What's the big deal? Idea can't compile .scala.html files. You also can try to have Play running with "~run", which will compile files as soon as they are written. Not sure Idea will detect these new files right away.

Comment: Yah it's not entirely a huge deal at the moment. I suppose the plugin will be updated soon enough and make this step unnecessary. Thanks for the input

Comment: What version of the plugins are you using? They are having some massive problems with the plugins right now. Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17329977/intellij-play2-and-scala-plugins-are-not-compatible-makes-intellij-12-no-longer

Comment: if my answer solved you question, please mark as resolved, thanks.

Answer (score 14):

If you use IDEA **Community** edition, there is a SBT Console plugin (see http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin?pluginId=5007) that allows you to compile / run your Play project directly in the editor. That's the way I work every day and it is fine (I use the `~run` command and then don't care anymore).

You may also add a remote debugger in IDEA that listens to you local server (it it is run with debug mode on) and use it as usual.

If you use IDEA **Ultimate** edition, JetBrains released a Play Framework plugin that seems to work fine (but I haven't tested it yet). Have a look at these tutorials:

- http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Play+Framework+2.0 or
- http://www.jamesward.com/2013/01/23/video-create-and-run-play-framework-apps-in-intellij

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how it work currently. As suggested by @pedrofurla, you can keep `~run` running on sbt/play console. Sadly, IMO there is no other way IntelliJ can compile your scala views automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Just add to `project/plugins.sbt` the following and re-run play idea

```
   // FIX SBT IDEA  PLAY 2.1  
   resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"  

  // Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects  
   addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.0")
```

Comment: With the latest version of Playframework this «trick» is no longer needed. http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/Migration22